# Dificuldade de autenticação no BD Informix

Tags: banco-de-dados, informix

Preciso desenvolver um pequeno relatório numa base legada com banco Informix (é a primeira vez que trabalho com Informix).

Porém estou tendo dificuldade de conexão. Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Connection failed: Incorrect password or user com.informix.asf.IfxASFRemoteException: informix@<usuário da minha máquina local> is not known on the database server.

Parece que ele está negando conexão a minha máquina.

Como libero o acesso ou desativo essa etapa da autenticação (a base não é de produção)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente você está informando a senha errada do usuário informix.

Se quiser liberar o acesso, "sem senha" , é preciso configurar o seu host como confiável. 
Isso pode ser feito de algumas maneiras, mas depende de qual plataforma e qual versão você está utilizando;

Método mais básico, fácil e rápido , em Linux/Unix :

- Adicione uma nova linha no arquivo **/etc/hosts.equiv** o IP da sua maquina.
  Pode tentar com o hostname, mas tem grandes chances de não funcionar.
  Este método vale a nível de sistema operacional, pode acabar liberando outros tipos de acesso a maquina.
  O efeito é imediato.

Se estiver utilizando windows o arquivo hosts.equiv fica na pasta `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc`. se não existir, pode criar.

Se tiver utilizando uma versão mais nova do banco , versão 11.70 ou superior não precisa alterar o hosts.equiv do S.O. , pode utilizar a versão especifica do banco:

- altere o parametro `REMOTE_SERVER_CFG <nome_arquivo>` onde o  será um arquivo que você irá criar na pasta $INFORMIXSERVER/etc , seguindo o mesmo padrão do hosts.equiv.
  Para alterar o parametro, com usuario informix, no servidor do banco :
  `onmode -wf REMOTE_SERVER_CFG=arquivoxyz`

Comment: Consegui. Fui no servidor e percebi que existia um usuário chamado "informix" no Windows (eu pensei que esse usuário era do banco). Realmente estava tentando a senha errada; depois que descobri a correta logo consegui acesso. Valeu pela força! :) (obs.: Como é difícil achar informações sobre o Informix na web!)